# Set Fragment's overflow icon to default

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, navigation-drawer

In my app, I have an activity implementing `NavigationDrawer`, `Toolbar` and two Fragments. In first Fragment I'm setting custom overflow icon, but in second fragment, I want to use system's default overflow icon and I don't want to use pre-downloaded drawable.
Should I create separate toolbars in each fragment and set them via `setSupportActionbar`, or is there a way to retrieve system's overflow icon?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured it out. Its a bit hacky way to do it, but works great. Code is in Kotlin but its just a simple call with cast.

In your main `Activity`, when creating toolbar call
`toolbar.tag = toolbar.overflowIcon` 
And in fragment where you want to restore your original overflow icon just do (On navigation activity's toolbar):
`toolbar.overflowIcon = toolbar.tag as Drawable`